# ESP-12F responds only to a few basic AT commands

Tags: esp8266, wifi

I previously read a few guides and tutorials about the ESP8266 and i just started using the ESP-12F module as i think that it is a terrific replacement for Arduino with the added benefit of Wi-Fi. I only have the module itself which is basically a metal casing so, i wired up the ESP-12F module according to this schematic.[image: ESP-12 module wire connections]

My USB-TTL board is operating at 3 V for its VCC and also for the TX and RX logic levels. I use Arduino IDE 1.8.9 (i made sure that i am using the latest stable version) and then set the COM port to the USB-TTL RS232 connected to the ESP12F and typed "AT" and got a response "OK". Then, i tried, "AT+RST" and got a big bunch of text which proved that there is successful communication with the ESP module. But then, i tried to connect the ESP-12F to my Wi-Fi network, so i entered: AT+CWJAP_CUR="SSID","password" replacing the SSID and password with my own and it gave the response "ERROR", so i tried the old format AT+CWJAP="SSID","password" and again i got "ERROR". So, what am i doing wrong? How to fix this? I was thinking that maybe the firmware on my ESP is old and needs to be updated, so i entered "AT+GMR" and i got this info:

```
19:07:27.560 -> ready
19:07:27.560 -> AT+GMR
19:07:27.560 -> AT version:1.2.0.0(Jul  1 2016 20:04:45)
19:07:27.560 -> SDK version:1.5.4.1(39cb9a32)
19:07:27.560 -> Ai-Thinker Technology Co. Ltd.
19:07:27.560 -> Dec  2 2016 14:21:16
19:07:27.560 -> OK
```

Do i need to update my module to be able to connect it to my Wi-Fi? If yes, how? I want to update it as safely as possible as this is my only ESP module and i don't want to inadvertently damage it.

Comment: Try `AT+CWMODE=1` first to put it into STA mode.

Comment: I did as you said and it worked! Thanks for the help. I will keep digging into the Espressif AT commands datasheet to learn more. By the way, is it advisable to update the firmware at this point?

Comment: Personally I never use the AT firmware. I always program the ESP8266 directly from the Arduino IDE (well, from UECIDE actually, but the principle is the same).

Comment: AT+CIUPDATE after you connected it to Internet

Answer (score 1):

You can't connect to an access point until you put the module into Station mode.

```
AT+CWMODE=1
```

That will put it in STA mode.  You can alternatively make it an access point (AP mode) with:

```
AP+CWMODE=2
```